# Else statement isn't triggering

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

The else statement is supposed to trigger when the user tries to select a food that
is out of stock, like pears, but it isn't working

```
stock = {'apples': 5, 'oranges': 2,  'pears': 0}

food = input('What food was eaten? ')
person = input('Who ate the food? ')

if food in stock:
    stock[food] -= 1
    print('{} ate {}'.format(person, food))
else:
    print('Food is out of stock')
```

Comment: The problem with your ```if``` condition is that it's checking if ```food``` is listed in ```stock``` which it is.    You need to add an additional condition such that it checks if there's available stock.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you are only checking if the food is in stock only.  You need to add an additional condition such that it checks if the food has available stock.

As in the following:

```
stock = {'apples': 5, 'oranges': 2,  'pears': 0}

food = input('What food was eaten? ')
person = input('Who ate the food? ')

if food in stock and stock[food] > 0:
    stock[food] -= 1
    print('{} ate {}'.format(person, food))
else:
    print('Food is out of stock')
```